# How to remove an item from list and add it to another list in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'm trying to remove an item from a list and add the exact element to another list variable, but apparently it gets overwritten.

Here is the code :

```
const [data, setData] = useState(["fridge", "milk", "dog", "cryptocurrency", "school", "blockchain", "developer", "engineer", "minecraft", "prison", "scofield", "twelve" ])
const [result, setResult] = useState([])
let temp_result = []
const handleWord = (w) => {


    for (var i=data.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (data[i] === w) {
            let element = data.splice(i, 1)
            setData([...data])
            temp_result.push(element[0])
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(temp_result)
}
```

Please find attached an image of the console (temp_result) : at `temp_result` is empty, first button click I removed `fridge` from `data` and pushed it to `temp_result`, second button click I removed `school` from `data` and pushed it to `temp_result`, but the `fridge` element is gone.

[image]

How can I avoid this ? Thanks in advance !

P.S : when I declare temp_result outside of my export function of the component, it works just fine, is this a normal behavior in react native ?

full code :

```
  import {useState} from 'react'
  let temp_result = []
  export default function Passphrase({ navigation }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(["fridge", "milk", "dog", "cryptocurrency", "school", "isychain", "developer","engineer", "minecraft", "prison", "scofield", "twelve" ])
const [result, setResult] = useState([])

const handleWord = (w) => {


    for (let i=data.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (data[i] === w) {
            let element = data.splice(i, 1)
            setData([...data])
            temp_result.push(element[0])
            break;
        }
    }
   setResult(temp_result)
}
return (<View></View>)
```

Comment: Whenever you set something, the component is re-rendered, so if you've defined `temp_result` to an empty array like that inside the `Passphrase` component, everything you do `setData` inside the handleWord function, the component is re-rendered and the `temp_result` is again initialized to empty array. 
Also don't know why you are setting result like this. You can directly set result instead of first pushing elements into a temporary array.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're not using the newest 'data' value when you do setData. [https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function][1]

Replace `setData([...data])` with `setData(currentData => [...currentData, ...thingsToAdd])`

This may be easier to read:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(["fridge", "milk", ...moreWords])

const handleWord = (wordToFind) => {
  const wordMatches = (word) => word === wordToFind;
  const indexOfWord = data.findIndex(wordMatches);

  if (indexOfWord) {
    setData(prev => {
      prev.filter(word => word === wordToFind); // remove the word
      return prev;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a problem with the `data` variable, it's the `temp_result`that gets overwritten !

Comment: I have updated the question, check the P.S section please.

Answer (score 1):

While updating state properties in React, you need to use the callback argument on setters, due to the asynchronous nature of state updates.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

```js
function handleWord(word) {
  setData((data)=> {
    return data.filter((w,i)=>{
      return w != word;
    });
  })
}
```

or shorthand:

```js
const handleWord = (word) => setData(data => data.filter((w, i) => w !== word));
```